# Cant get value in PHP array but var_dump shows that it exists

Tags: php, arrays, var-dump

Long time, my PHP-application ran on a linux server with apache and PHP.

Now I've set up a windows server with apache and php and simple PHP-Programs have problems.

```
var_dump($data);
die(var_dump($data['a']));
```

results in

```
object(stdClass)#1 (1) { ["a"]=> string(1) "b" } 
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in BLUB.php on line 14
```

var_dump says there is an index a. Why does $data['a'] throw an exception?

**EDIT**: $data is json_decode($something);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use:

```
 $data = json_decode($something, true);
```

To get array from json

Answer (score 3):

Because its an object, not an array. You cant access it like that. This would be correct:

```
$data->a;
```

Comment: Why did PHP change that? I think I have an older version of PHP on my linux server. json_decode always produced an array. But I will try that.

Comment: Dont know, but you can still get an array. You have to use `json_decode($something, true);` in that case, then you receive an array, not an object. You can see more here: http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.json-decode.php

Comment: By the way, who downvoted me? Its not that i really care about up- or downvotes, but you could at least tell me where i did a mistake so i might improve it for the future.

Comment: @DanielBrunner - PHP didn't ___change___ anything (arrays are still arrays), they ___added___ something (objects)

Comment: @DanielBrunner, you use `json_decode()` which return object, or array if you pass second argument `true`

Answer (score 3):

The error contains your answer - $data is actually an object of type stdClass.  You could either:

a) access the property 'a' with $data->a
or
b) typecast $data as an array using (array)$data

Comment: Thanks for the idea with casting it! Now I only have to cast it once and I am able to use my old code.

Answer (score 2):

As the error says `$data` is an object, not an array. As such, you want to use object access, rather than array access. In this case, that would be `var_dump($data->a)`

Answer (score 0):

since `$data` in an object you have to access it this way:

```
$data->a;
```

Otherwise, you can typecast it to an array and access it actually like an array

```
$dataArr = (array) $data;

$dataArr['a'];
```

**NOTE**

This is possible only whether your object attributes are `public`